# DO jmeter 4.0 supports for http 2 load test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

Is it possible to record http2 request in jmeter and i have converted my existing http script to http2 in that my regular expression extractor is not working properly it is responding with not found.can any one pls guide me on this

I have pasted the jar list to my lib/ext folder alpn-api-1.1.3.v20160715.jar, netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha2.jar, netty-tcnative-2.0.7.Final.jar, hpack-1.0.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

Per se it doesn't, however there is [HTTP2 Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/tree/master/http2) which adds HTTP2 protocol support to JMeter.

[image: JMeter Install HTTP2 Sampler]

You can install HTTP/2 Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)